# Is "diversified" really a suitable translation for what Germans call "abwechslungsreich"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, translation, german

I need a word to describe a meeting or conference or other event which was the opposite of boring due to the variation of activities there.*

German language has *abwechslungsreich*, literally *rich-of-changes*. All dictionaries I have available recommend *diversified*, but then, more precise definitions all meander around "diversifying a business" etc., and that's quite a different thing.

So, what would native speakers use to describe a meeting that is pleasant for attendants because there is enough (but not too much) variation in activities?

Note: *abwechslungsreich* is very often used also for landscapes. Would

> Bulgaria has a diversified landscape.

be a good sentence? My feeling is: rather not. But what could be used instead?

---

*) I do not mean *interesting*, which one could claim is the primary opposite of boring. *Interesting* is regarding the contents of a meeting and the attitude of an attendant towards it. *Abwechslungsreich* however is about the agenda of the meeting.

Comment: Probably ***varied*** is a better choice. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+jig+is+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20jig%20is%20up%3B%2Cc0

Comment: **Varied** would suit both the conference and the landscape. I assume the 'not' in the previous comment is a typo.

Comment: I suggest you ask here. https://german.stackexchange.com/  or here  - https://forum.wordreference.com/forums/deutsch-german.18/

Comment: @chaslyfromUK   I am a very active contributor to german.stackexchange myself. That is not the right place for asking for English synonyms....

Comment: Aside: **attendant** is grammatically correct but **attendee** would be clearer: someone attending the meeting (a delegate), not one of the venue's staff (a servant).

Comment: [Dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/abwechslungsreich) says 'diversified' and 'varied'

Comment: @WeatherVane   - Thank you for the side-note on andendant vs. attendees. So you recommend generally for people who attend a meeting, a course, a seminar, event etc. to use *attendee* rather than *attendant*? - If so, a long thread of project reports (by me and many colleagues) would be awkwardly worded. Or is it a question of US vs. European usage?

Comment: Ah, as a BrE speaker I had to look up that usage of "attendant" as I had always understood it to mean someone who **attends to ones needs**. For example a **car park attendant** isn't looking for somewhere to park.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The German *abwechslungsreich* means not only ‘varied, diverse’ but that such variety is interesting or entertaining. There is no single English word that does both, so you have to use two adjectives instead of one:

> We have a [*varied and interesting*](http://www.nhsrf.org.uk/NewForest.pdf) programme, including speakers, bring and buy, raffle, coach outings and walks in the New Forest, Strawberry Tea, mince pies and sherry, Christmas Lunch and social activities. — New Forest Branch
>
> Vegetarian food can be as [*varied and interesting*](https://www.thewestmorlandgazette.co.uk/NEWS/15786777.AGONY_CHEF__vegetarian_food_can_be_as_varied_and_interesting_as_non_vegetarian_food/) as non-vegetarian food. This time of year, look at what vegetables are in season  and take your inspiration from there. — Agony Chef, *Westmoreland Gazette*, 30 Dec. 2017.
>
> The work of a Garden Designer is [*varied and interesting*](http://www.janinecrimmins.com/varied-interesting-work-garden-designer/) and occasionally requests arrive for something out of the ordinary. — Janine Crimmins, Garden Design, 19 Oct. 2014.
>
> The concert consisted of many traditional songs together with some more modern renditions and the addition of some African songs made a very [*varied and interesting*](http://www.pressreader.com/uk/the-scarborough-news/20110506/282973921605114) evening. — *Scarborough News* (UK), 6 May 2011.

You can raise the entertainment factor with *fun and varied*:

> Create a [*fun and varied*](https://bellyfull.net/2015/07/15/creating-a-hot-dog-bar/) hot dog bar with all your favorite add-ons for the best summer grilling party! — Belly Full, 15 July 2015.

Or stick the fun part in an adverb:

> Cannes Market. Located along one of the Côte d'Azur's best gourmand streets, Forville Market offers visitors to Cannes a [*delightfully varied*](https://www.radissonblu.com/de/hotel-cannes/standort/cannes-market) eating and food shopping experience among its produce and flower stalls. — Radisson Blu Hotels

These examples hardly exhaust the possibilities, but the point is that in English you’ll likely need one word for variety and one for fun, not just one as in German that does double duty.

Comment: Yes, this exactly was my impression... that there is no a single-word solution. I like your "varied and interesting" word combination!